# BIM and IoT sensor integration

Tags: integration, iot, autodesk-forge, bim

I am working on BIM and IoT sensor integration for the digital twin and I intend to use Autodesk Platform Services for the integration.I previously used the developer's guide for Data Visualization Extension. But I'm facing difficulties because I can't find the developer's guide for BIM and IoT integration now. I would be extremely grateful if you could please share the developer's guide for BIM and IoT Integration for the digital twin through the Autodesk platform services.

Answer (score 0):

We've simplified the sample application for Data Visualization integrations.

Please, refer to our updated [documentation](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/dataviz/v1/developers_guide/overview/) and [sample](https://github.com/autodesk-platform-services/aps-iot-extensions-demo).
​